# Programmatically Resize Traitsui Window

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I have a traitsui gui inheriting from HasTraits (with a HSplit between a mayavi plot and a panel with editable traits). When I call .configure_traits(), the size of the resulting window seems to depend on screen size only, not on content (on OS X 10.7 and 10.8). Is there a way to make the window (in particular the panel with the editable traits) fit the size of its content?

Answer (score 1):

You should include a code sample that demonstrates the issue you are seeing.  TraitsUI normally generates a window that is the minimum size to contain the [attributes](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/_images/ui_for_ex1.jpg): [image: example]

But if you specify a size, you'll get either an absolute size:

```
    view = View(Item('figure', show_label=False),
                width=400, height=300, resizable=True)
```

or a percentage of the screen:

```
    view = View(Item('figure', show_label=False),
                width=.5, height=.5, resizable=True)
```

depending on what you asked for.  What does your code say?